# How to access variables needed to create a URL for a New Relationship without hard coding it?

Tags: apex, urlhacking, url

Created a page for account and one for a contact, with a "Create new Relationship" button. You select with you want to relate with a contact or an account, and based on that it creates a URL for the type of relationship needed (contact-contact, contact-account, account-contact, account-account), and it pre-populates the name of the first object.
The problem is, how can i create these URLs by using salesforce variables/methods instead of hardcoding it?

For example:

- a0a - means new relationship. How can i not hardcoded a0a to the url?
- e?retURL - means redirect the url to this Edit page. how can i not hard code that?
- CF00No00000020GfN- translates to the name of the first contact when creating a new relationship
- CF00No00000020GfM - translates to the name of the first account
- %20 - whitespace
- %26 - & character

I know what most of these mean, but i don't want to hardcode this values, i want to be able to access this values from a salesforce variable, method, or etc.

For example:

- URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() results in login.salesforce.com

where can i access more of these?

Part of my code below:

```
public PageReference newRelationshipButtonClicked(){

    String urlToGoTo = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/a0a/';

    if(firstObjectIsAccount){
        if(secondObjectIsAccount){ //both are accounts

            String accountName = myAccount.Name.replace(' ','%20');
            accountName = accountName.replace('&', '%26');
            urlToGoTo += 'e?retURL=%2Fa0a&RecordType=012o0000000Jz9n&ent=01Io0000000Y6H1&CF00No00000020GfM='+accountName;

            } else { //im account, person i wanna have a relation to is a contact

                 String accountName = myAccount.Name.replace(' ','%20');
                 accountName = accountName.replace('&', '%26');
                 urlToGoTo += 'e?retURL=%2Fa0a&RecordType=012o0000000Jz9m&ent=01Io0000000Y6H1&CF00No00000020GfM='+accountName;

                 }

        } else { //im a contact
            if(secondObjectIsAccount){ //im a contact, other is an account
                urlToGoTo += 'e?retURL=%2Fa0a&RecordType=012o0000000Jz9l&ent=01Io0000000Y6H1&CF00No00000020GfN='+myContact.FirstName+'%20'+myContact.LastName;
                } else{ //we are both contacts
                    urlToGoTo += 'e?retURL=%2F003o0000002ITxg&CF00No00000020GfN='+myContact.FirstName+'%20'+myContact.LastName;
                    }
            }
            PageReference newRelationshipPage = new PageReference(urlToGoTo);
            newRelationshipPage.setRedirect(true);
             return newRelationshipPage;
             }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you might be looking for is $Action.

In short, it can be used in a VF page like so:

```
<apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.Account.New)}">
    Create New Account
</apex:outputLink>
```

This link shows you a complete list of what $Action can do:
https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_variables_global_action_valid_values.htm

This is a link to show you how you can accomplish some dynamic routing using $action:
https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_dynamic_vf_globals_action.htm

Best of luck!

-Wes

Answer (score 0):

URL Class is where you have more URL  params:
https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_url.htm

Some of the other params you have here can be saved in a static resource/ custom label and can be accessed from there if you do not want to hardcore in the code.

Comment: I read over that link before, as you can see I use it to do this: URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()

My question is, how do i get the URL/Id for a table/field.
For example, i have an custom object called Relationship_Detail__c, and i can get an Id for an specific row/relationship using this id. But i want the id for the table.

E.g, Account's super id is 001, and an specific account is something like: 001o0000003MZNl.
How can i acces 001 without hardcoding it?

Answer (score 0):

With the advent of the Tooling API, the field Ids become available to your controller; prefixes of sobjects were always available with Describe calls

Apex wrapper to REST Tooling API is here: https://github.com/afawcett/apex-toolingapi

The solution is covered in depth here: http://andyinthecloud.com/2014/01/05/querying-custom-object-and-field-ids-via-tooling-api/

Answer (score 0):

You can try 'Custom Label' in Salesforce.
VF page: "{!$Label.LabelName}
Apex class : System.Label.LabelName